# Check if all items in list are one of the items in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string input by a user (e.g. `"MMXVII"`), then I make it an array using `list(User_input)`. Now, I want to check if each character the user has input matches one of the characters in another array containing allowed characters.

So I'd have two lists:

```
List_Permitted_Characters = ["M", "G", etc . ]
User_input = ["M", "M, "X", "V", "I", "I"]
```

I need to check if every character in `User_input` is one of the ones in `List_Permitted_Characters`

I'm quite new to programming and python, so I'm sorry if this information isn't very helpful.

Comment: Before you choose an approach, think about what you need to do if one or more characters are _not_ on the allowed list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is using sets:

```
set(User_input).issubset(List_Permitted_Characters)
```

If this is all you are using `List_Permitted_Characters` for, you should store is as a set anyway, since the sequential information is irrelevant.